# getting arguments from command line python

Tags: python

I am trying to get three arguments from command line:

```
-o (for outputfile) -k (number of clusters) -l (data to be clustered)
```

So i wrote this.

```
def get_input():
print 'ARGV      :', sys.argv[1:]

options, remainder = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'o:v:k:l', ['output=', 
                                                     'verbose',
                                                     'k_clust=',
                                                     'limit='])
print "options ",options
file_flag , k_flag, count_flag = False, False,False
for opt, arg in options:
    print opt
    if opt in ('-o', '--output'):
        print "here ", opt, arg
        output_filename = arg
        o_flag = True

    if opt in ('-v', '--verbose'):
        verbose = True
    if opt == '--version':
        version = arg

    if opt in ('-k','--k_clust'):
        print "here", opt, arg
        k_clust = arg
        k_flag = True

    if opt in ('-l','--limit'):
         kcount = arg
         assert kcount!=0 and kcount!= ''
         print "limit ", arg
         count_flag = True
if k_flag == False:
    sys.exit(" no cluster specified, will be exiting now")
if o_flag == False:
    print "using default outfile name ",output_filename
if count_flag == False:
   kcount = 10000000


return output_filename, k_clust,kcount
```

Everything is working on fine except the -l flag
so if my command line command is this:

```
$python foo.py -o foo.txt -k 2 -l 2
```

and the print argv prints

```
ARGV      : ['-o', 'demo.txt', '-k', '2', '-l', '2']
```

but the options is:

```
options  [('-o', 'demo.txt'), ('-k', '2'), ('-l', '')]
```

Notice that nothing is being parsed in the "l" field.
Wat am i doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`getopt` is a rather old module. If you have Python2.7, use [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse).
If you have a slightly older version of Python >= 2.3, you can still [install argparse](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/argparse):

With

```
import argparse
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-o', help = 'outputfile')
parser.add_argument('-k', help = 'number of clusters')
parser.add_argument('-l', help = 'data to be clustered')
args=parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

running

```
test.py -o foo.txt -k 2 -l 2
```

yields

```
Namespace(k='2', l='2', o='foo.txt')
```

Answer (score 4):

It's because in your shortopts parameter: 'o:v:k:l', the "l" needs to be followed by a colon ":"

Since it's not, the "2" is being put into the remainder variable.