# Break statement in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to break out of a for loop, but for some reason the following doesn't work as expected:

```
for out in dbOutPut:
    case_id = out['case_id']
    string = out['subject']
    vectorspace = create_vector_space_model(case_id, string, tfidf_dict)
    vectorspace_list.append(vectorspace)
    case_id_list.append(case_id)

    print len(case_id_list)

    if len(case_id_list) >= kcount:
        print "true"
        break
```

It just keeps iterating untill the end of `dbOutput`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `kcount`? Please show *all* relevant parts of your code.

Comment: hi kcount is a variable  i am inputting..but its way less than the size of that list..kcount = 20...and total length of dboutput is like 100000

Comment: Have you tried adding `print kcount` to verify condition is actually met?

Comment: Does it ever print true?  If not then your if statement isn't being triggered, so your break is never happening.

Comment: nopes?? it doesnt goes to that loop..though i see that length increasing?

Comment: @Fraz: I'm suggesting that your `kcount` is not an integer. It might be a string (and so Python is not doing what you expect when you compare an integer with a string). Please show the code that initialises `kcount`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing, based on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039320/getting-arguments-from-command-line-python), that `kcount` is a string, not an int. Note that when you compare an int with a string, (in CPython version 2) the [int is always less than the string](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) because `'int'` comes before `'str'` in alphabetic order:

```
In [12]: 100 >= '2'
Out[12]: False
```

If `kcount` is a string, then the solution is add a type to the `argparse` argument:

```
import argparse
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-k', type = int, help = 'number of clusters')
args=parser.parse_args()
print(type(args.k))   
print(args.k)
```

running

```
% test.py -k 2
```

yields

```
<type 'int'>
2
```

---

This confusing error would not arise in Python3. There, comparing an `int` and a `str` raises a TypeError.

Answer (score 4):

Could it happen that `kcount` is actually a string, not an integer and, therefore, could never become less than any integer?
See string to int comparison in python [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int) for more details.